# JENKINS unmappable character for encoding UTF8

Tags: java, linux, maven, jenkins, tomcat7

Hello im u using jenkins with tomcat and when i create a simple maven project in jenkins and make the configuration of GIT plugin and Maven but when i build my project i find this error :
unmappable character for encoding UTF8

i trying to add `<encodage> UTF-8 </encodage>` into my pom

but not working

this is my parent pom :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>fr</groupId>
  <artifactId>trunk</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>B</module>
    <module>C</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

and this is the pom of core :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>fr</groupId>
            <artifactId>trunk</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>
        <groupId>fr.pc30</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <dependencies>
...
...
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

this a pic of error 
[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eaUA.png][1]

Comment: First I would suggest to add an appropriate property like [described here](https://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning) and furthermore your code seemed to containing wrong encoding characters...

Comment: my code in my local machine maven with encodage cp1252 and my code working but im my machine linux maven used encoadage UTF-8 for that make some probleme to me

Comment: i adding the <properties> utf8 </properties> and i add <encodage>utf8 </encodage> then i change my local project from cp1252 to utf8 and when i run the commande mvn compile in my local evry think working ok but in my machine linux they dont work and still the same ERROR